# What is the difference between the cartesian product and direct sum of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum, direct-product

My notes give the cartesian product of the sets $X_1, . . . , X_n$ as
$$X_1 × · · · × X_n = \{(x_1, . . . , x_n) : x_i ∈ X_i for 1 \le i \le n\}$$
I believe we can think of a vector space $V$ where $V=F^n$ as the cartesian product of $n$ copies of a set $F$, where $F$ is the ground field.

Also, given a field $F$ and F-vector spaces $V_1, . . . , V_n$, it can be shown that the cartesian product $V_1 × · · · × V_1$ is also an
F-vector space if we define addition and multiplication by scalars componentwise. I would understand this to look like:
$$V_1 × · · · × V_n = \{(v_1, . . . , v_n) : v_i ∈ V_i for 1 \le i \le n\}$$
My notes then give a different notation of the above cartesian product as:
$$V_1 ⊕ · · · ⊕ V_n$$
and we refer to it as the product or the direct sum or the external direct sum.
Is this simply
$$V_1 ⊕ · · · ⊕ V_n = \{(v_1+ . . . + v_n) : v_i ∈ V_i for 1 \le i \le n\}$$?
If so, how are these equivalent sets?
Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be a simple misunderstanding of notation. $V\bigoplus W$ is not $\{v+w\}$, it is just the algebraic notation for pairs $(v,w)$ (see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum). To avoid confusion, think of it like this. If $V$ and $W$ have different underlying sets, the operation $v+w$ might not even make sense. E.g., if $V$ is $\mathbb{R}$ and $W$ is the set of $2\times 2$ matrices.

Comment: Cartesian product and direct sums are exactly the same thing, when there are a finite number of summands. They are only different when an infinite number of spaces are being summed.

Comment: @AnCar thank you, that example does help. Although could you explain where $⨁ =\{(+):_ \in _, w_ \in W_ 1\le \le \}$ does apply, as I am certain I have seen this before. Does this only apply to the internal direct sum where $V_1⨁V_2=$ where $V_1$ and $V_2$ are complementary vector subspaces of $V$?

Comment: @rileygrey65 Not sure about the most general scope. I would say that you can write it like that whenever you can identify in a meaningful way $v+w$ with the pair $(v,w)$, as is the case for example of complementary subspaces. I just think of the notation $V\bigoplus W$ to mean cartesian product when there is some underlying algebraic structure at play.

Comment: @MJD what's the difference with infinite number of spaces?

Comment: An element of the cartesian product is an element of the direct sum only if it  has a finite number of nonzero components. For finite products, every element has a  finite number of nonzero components.